# Set cookie on local server

Tags: php, dns, local, setcookie

I'm developing a site on local server, so the url of the site is http:/goodies/, there is no domain ending like ".com"

How can I make this code work?

```
setcookie('user', $user_check, time() + (86400 * 3), '/', 'goodies');
```

Comment: The `$path` and `$domain` arguments are optional. You can leave them out.

Comment: Ah, thanks mate. Manual says "[, string $domain [, bool $secure = false [, bool $httponly = false ]]]" without default value, so I thought it should be given.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just don't pass `$domain` argument. It is not required http://php.net/manual/function.setcookie.php